# JavaScriptSerializer and monodevelop

Tags: serialization, xamarin.ios, javascriptserializer

Im reading [this book](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-iPhone-Programming-with-MonoTouch-and-NET-C-.productCd-047063782X.html) but I JavaScriptSerializer from the System.Web.Script.Serialization namespace because it seems to be unavailable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download source here and add as existing project.
Then add as reference:

http://www.bloxify.com/post/MonoTouch-Easy-JSON-Library.aspx

Edit:

You may also find that the monotouch linker is pretty aggressive.  I would have code work fine in the simulator but crash in the device with method missing exceptions.  Add a method somewhere in your app (you dont have to call it) like so:

```
    public void FixMonoTouchErrors()
    {
        var gc = new System.ComponentModel.GuidConverter();
        var sc = new System.ComponentModel.StringConverter();
        var dc = new System.ComponentModel.DateTimeConverter();
        var cc = new System.ComponentModel.CharConverter();
        var sh = new System.ComponentModel.Int16Converter();
        var sh1 = new System.ComponentModel.Int32Converter();
        var sh2 = new System.ComponentModel.Int64Converter();
        var dec = new System.ComponentModel.DecimalConverter();
        var nc0 = new System.ComponentModel.NullableConverter(typeof(Int16?));
        var nc1 = new System.ComponentModel.NullableConverter(typeof(Int32?));
        var nc2 = new System.ComponentModel.NullableConverter(typeof(Int64?));
        var nc3 = new System.ComponentModel.NullableConverter(typeof(decimal?));
        var nc4 = new System.ComponentModel.NullableConverter(typeof(DateTime?));
    }
```

Comment: Okay, thanks!
Yesterday I used System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer instead but thanks anyway,

Comment: I am wondering what API do you call that causes this crash?   We can make the above happen automatically if you tell us what triggered it.

Comment: I am wondering what API do you call that causes this crash?   We can make the above happen automatically if you tell us what triggered it.

Comment: I believe for me it was the code posted on the (now dead) link wrapping NewtonSoft JSON.NET to fit the JavaScriptSerializer APIs.

Answer (score 7):

I know this a really old post but by chance someone stumbles upon this like I have, System.Web.Script.Serialization is available in [System.Web.Extensions](http://go-mono.com/status/status.aspx?reference=3.5&profile=2.0&assembly=System.Web.Extensions).